# Haskell regex context ambiguous type despite explicit Bool type annotation, succeeds in ghci

Tags: haskell, ghci

This works in an interpreter session

```
λ> import Text.Regex.Base
λ> import Text.Regex.Posix
λ> import Data.List (sort)
λ> import System.Directory

λ> ls <- getDirectoryContents "."
λ> let csvs = sort $ filter (\x -> x =~ "csv$" :: Bool) ls
λ> recent = last csvs
```

This is great and gives me exactly what I need.

However, the same code fails to compile in a script:

```
t10.hs:40:35-45: error: …
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘source0’ arising from a use of ‘=~’
      prevents the constraint ‘(RegexMaker
                                  Regex CompOption ExecOption source0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘source0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance RegexMaker Regex CompOption ExecOption C.ByteString
          -- Defined in ‘Text.Regex.Posix.ByteString’
        instance RegexMaker Regex CompOption ExecOption LB.ByteString
          -- Defined in ‘Text.Regex.Posix.ByteString.Lazy’
    • In the expression: x =~ "csv$" :: Bool
      In the first argument of ‘filter’, namely
        ‘(\ x -> x =~ "csv$" :: Bool)’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘filter (\ x -> x =~ "csv$" :: Bool) ls’
t10.hs:40:40-45: error: …
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘source0’ arising from the literal ‘"csv$"’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Data.String.IsString
                                  source0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘source0’ should be.
```

I have an explicit `:: Bool` context at the end to provide exactly this information.  Why would this be succeeding in ghci but failing to catch this same instruction when compiling, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ambiguity is not about what the type of `x =~ "csv$"` is - that is already determined from your use of `filter`. The problem is the `"csv$"` literal itself. Based on the error message, you have the `OverloadedStrings` language extension enabled. The ambiguity here is figuring out which type of string `"csv$"` needs to be.

Your solution is to either

- turn off `OverloadedStrings` (if you don't need it for this module), or
- add a type annotation to `"csv$"`, so you have `\x -> x =~ ("csv$" :: String)` instead of `\x -> x =~ "csv$" :: Bool`

If this is a problem that is cropping up a lot, you may want to play with the `ExtendedDefaultRules` and have a `default` declaration in your file.

The reason this succeeds in GHCi is probably because because you didn't have `OverloadedStrings` enabled there (or possibly due to GHCi's different defaulting rules).

Comment: Got it.  Ended up needing OverloadedStrings, so went with:   
let csvs = sort $ filter (\x -> x =~ ("csv$" :: String) :: Bool) ls

Comment: @Mittenchops If you are using `filter` from the Prelude, `let csvs = sort $ filter (\x -> x =~ ("csv$" :: String)) ls`  is enough (no need for the `:: Bool`).